# Any way to make this easier? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

This is a python problem where the code was supposed to allow you to input n number of names and scores, and the program would return the name or names of those with the second lowest score. This is what I cam up with and it works perfectly fine but in the interest of getting better I was wondering if there are any simpler ways to accomplish this. My code is below.

```
n=int(input())
names=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    names.append([input(),float(input())])
for i in range(0,n):
    names[i].reverse()
names.sort()
names.reverse()
misc=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    misc.append(names[i][0])
blank=[]
for i in misc:
    if i not in blank:
        blank.append(i)
blank.reverse()
vals=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    if names[i][0]==blank[1]:
        vals.append(names[i])
vals.reverse()
for i in range(0,len(vals)):
    print(vals[i][1])
```

Comment: This question is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Please post it there

Comment: You can use `misc = list(set(misc))` to quickly remove duplicates. But you'll have to sort it again. In that case, you don't need to sort names.

Comment: @Goion: the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the structure could be greatly simplified with dicts.

Start with getting a dict names vs scores. e.g.:

```
name_to_score = {
   "alice": 1.2,
   "bob": 1.1,
   "fred": 1.3,
   "nancy": 1.2,
}
```

Then take that dict and invert it to have a dict of scores vs names:

```
score_to_names = {
   1.2: ["alice", "nancy"],
   1.1: ["bob"],
   1.3: ["fred"],
}
```

You can find the second lowest score (key) and print out the values from the inverted dict.

Your implementation could look something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_to_score = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name_to_score[input()] = float(input())

score_to_names = defaultdict(list)
for name, score in name_to_score.items():
    score_to_names[score].append(name)

second_lowest_score = sorted(score_to_names.keys())[1]
print(score_to_names[second_lowest_score])
```

You could also start off by creating the `score_to_names` dict right away:

```
from collections import defaultdict

score_to_names = defaultdict(list)
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    score_to_names[score].append(name)

second_lowest_score = sorted(score_to_names.keys())[1]
print(score_to_names[second_lowest_score])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard to read. If you improve readability it will make it easier for you and everybody else to understand what is happening.

The first step would be to split it into 3 parts:

- Getting input from a user
- Calculating the result
- Displaying result to a user

Then I would consider renaming variables. I cannot tell what `blank`, `misc` and `vals` are and why you use `reverse()` so often.

---

In pyhton there is build in `min()` function [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min).

I would combine it with `defaultdict` from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

and used them like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

scores_names = defaultdict(list)  # {3:["Johny", "Sanny"], 4:[Ben]}
# Getting input from a user
n = int(input("n:"))
for i in range(0, n):
    scores_names[float(input("score:"))].append(input("name:"))
# Calculating the result
min_score = min(scores_names.keys())
result = scores_names[min_score]
# Displaying result to a user
print(result)
```

Console:

```
n:3
score:3
name:Johny
score:3
name:Sanny
score:4
name:Ben
['Johny', 'Sanny']
```

---

If you want your code to look nice and follow PEP8 consider using [Black](https://github.com/psf/black)

If you want to learn more on how to refactor consider reading this [book](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html)